# SolrCloud OpenNLP error Can't find resource 'opennlp/en-sent.bin' in classpath or '/configs/_default'

Tags: solr, nlp, solrcloud, opennlp

I have error when using Apache OpenNLP with Solr (ver. 7.3.0) in Cloud mode. 
When I add field type to *managed-schema* using open nlp like this:

```
<fieldType name="text_opennlp" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.OpenNLPTokenizerFactory"
          sentenceModel="opennlp/en-sent.bin"
          tokenizerModel="opennlp/en-token.bin"
        />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <field name="content" type="text_opennlp" indexed="true" termOffsets="true" stored="true" termPayloads="true" termPositions="true" docValues="false" termVectors="true" multiValued="true" required="true"/>
```

and I have following error:

> test_collection_shard1_replica_n1:  org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core test_collection_shard1_replica_n1: Can't load  schema managed-schema: org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceNotFoundException:  Can't find resource 'opennlp/en-sent.bin' in classpath or '/configs/_default',  cwd=D:\utils\solr-7.3.0-7\solr-7.3.0-7\server Please check your logs for more information

I have downloaded solr var 7.3.0-7 from https://builds.apache.org/job/Solr-Artifacts-7.3/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/solr/package/

I tried to put model files to: `D:\utils\solr-7.3.0-7\solr-7.3.0-7\server` but it didn't help.

Here you are my related question: [Can not apply patch LUCENE-2899.patch to SOLR on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433989/can-not-apply-patch-lucene-2899-patch-to-solr-on-windows/49435028?noredirect=1#comment85988550_49435028)

Maybe I need to put model files somewhere else?

Comment: Maybe someone used apache open nlp with solr and knows where this models should be located?

Comment: Maybe I need to use Zookeeper to upload files somehow but how can I do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put those files (`"en-sent.bin"` and the other one) into core's conf directory.

That is `D:\utils\solr-7.3.0-7\solr-7.3.0-7\server\{core_name}\conf`.

Then use the files directly. Following should be the xml configuration.

```
<tokenizer class="solr.OpenNLPTokenizerFactory"
          sentenceModel="en-sent.bin"
          tokenizerModel="en-token.bin"
        />
```