# Upload file(binary) into Zookeeper (SolrCloud)

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am using SolrCloud on Windows and I need to upload OpenNLP model files(binary files) into Zookeeper. How can I do this?

Here are my related questions:

- [Can not apply patch LUCENE-2899.patch to SOLR on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433989/can-not-apply-patch-lucene-2899-patch-to-solr-on-windows/49435028?noredirect=1#comment85988550_49435028)
- [SolrCloud OpenNLP error Can't find resource 'opennlp/en-sent.bin' in classpath or '/configs/_default'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49507004/solrcloud-opennlp-error-cant-find-resource-opennlp-en-sent-bin-in-classpath-o)